# Delete element from a associative array in JavsScript --> very slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete one element from  a associative array. The array is as follows:

```
array[propertyname] = property;
```

This array is filled with some data (less than 10 entries) and is shown in a property window.

On certain pages you can click a delete button next to the entries and delete that corresponding entry. To achieve that this function is called:

```
$d(document).on('click', '.property_del[type="button"]', function(event) {
   for (property in selectedGroup.properties) {
      if(property == $d(this).attr('id').replace("_buttondel", "")){
         continue;
      }else{
         temp_array[property] = selectedGroup.properties[property];
      }
selectedGroup.properties = temp_array;
});
```

This works so far, the selected entry is deleted after the button click event, but it is slow as hell. The second method to delete is as slow as the first one:

```
delete selectedGroup.properties[$d(this).attr('id').replace("_buttondel", "")];
```

What can I do to make it even faster?

THX!!

Comment: How do you experience "slow"?

Comment: The answers provided are a way to speed things up but if you really want to speed things up go for native javascript instead of jQuery.

Comment: The whole thing with the associative array is executed very slow after some time. The solution with "var that = $(this);" makes it a bit faster but don't solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

maybe the jquery selector inside the for loop is slowing things down.  does this speed things up:

```
$d(document).on('click', '.property_del[type="button"]', function(event) {
   var value = $d(this).attr('id').replace("_buttondel", "");
   for (property in selectedGroup.properties) {
      if(property == value){
         continue;
      }else{
         temp_array[property] = selectedGroup.properties[property];
      }
selectedGroup.properties = temp_array;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will be wasting a lot of time on the jquery "constructor", as you do `$(this)` inside your `for` loop. Depending on the amount of properties in `selectedGroup.properties`, that will be a considerable amount of time.
As a start, I'd use

```
var that = $(this);
var truncatedId = that.attr('id').replace("_buttondel", "");
```

outside the for loop.